# Image cropping and zooming in circular format in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

[image]

Here I'm trying to zoom cropped area and trying to do dropped area in circular format, but I didn't a get proper solution for this. So please help me anybody know this?

```
CALayer* layer = self.blurredImageView.layer;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextAddRect(c, self.cropArea);
CGContextAddRect(c, rect);
CGContextEOClip(c);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextFillRect(c, rect);
UIImage* maskim = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: happy new year, set imagview layer frame with your CG layer, and imageview clipping=true

Comment: Hey Take a look at the sample https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rskimagecropper

Answer (score 1):

There is ready library on [GitHub](https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSKImageCropper) for round cropping like default contacts app of iOS.This may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set your UIImageView's corner radius to half of it's width.

Like:

```
imgHspt.layer.cornerRadius = imgHspt.frame.size.width/2.0f;
imgHspt.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
imgHspt.clipsToBounds = YES;
imgHspt.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This works with every image.
Hope it works.